# Segfault in a simple malloc and free implementation

Tags: assembly, memory-management, x86, malloc

**TLDR;**

I over-rode the `malloc` and `free` with a custom logic. The program is `segfault`ing, however. Is there anything I am missing? Eventually, I was able to test it with a simple `malloc` and `free` call but without using any of the `stdio.h` features. Why is that happening?

**Full Version**

I wrote a 32-bit assembly program to over-ride `malloc` and `free` using `LD_PRELOAD`.

```
        # PURPOSE:  Program to replace malloc and free using LD_PRELOAD
        #
        # NOTES:    The programs using these routines will ask for a certain
        #           size of memory. We actually use more than that size, but we
        #           put it at the beginning, before the pointer we hand back.
        #           We add a Size field and an Available/Unavailable marker. So
        #           the memory looks like this:
        #
        #           #########################################################
        #           #Available Marker#Size of Memory#Actual Memory Locations#
        #           #########################################################
        #                                            ^Returned pointer points
        #                                             here
        #
        #           The pointer we return only points to the actual locations
        #           requested to make it easier for the calling program. It
        #           also allows us to change our structure without the calling
        #           program having to change at all.
        #
        #           The _alloc-lib-test.c program can test it:
        #           Dump the output and read it using hexdump.


        .section .data

# Global variables

# This points to the beginning of the memory we are managing

heap_begin:
        .long 0

# This points to one location past the memory we are managing

current_break:
        .long 0

# Structure information

        .equ HEADER_SIZE, 8       # Size of space for memory region header
        .equ HDR_AVAIL_OFFSET, 0  # Location of the "Available" flag in the
                                  # header
        .equ HDR_SIZE_OFFSET, 4   # Location of the size field in the header

# Constants

        .equ UNAVAILABLE, 0  # This is the number we will use to mark space
                             # that has been given out
        .equ AVAILABLE, 1    # This is the number we will use to mark space
                             # that has been returned, and is available for
                             # giving
        .equ SYS_BRK, 45     # break system call

        .equ LINUX_SYSCALL, 0x80

        .section .text

# Functions

# allocate_init starts

        # PURPOSE:  Call this function to initialize the functions
        #           (specifically, this sets heap_begin and current_break).
        #
        # PARAMS:   None
        #
        # RETURN:   None

        .globl allocate_init
        .type allocate_init,@function

allocate_init:

        pushl %ebp                  # Standard function stuff
        movl  %esp, %ebp

        # If the brk system call is called with 0 in %ebx, it returns the last
        # valid usable address

        movl  $SYS_BRK, %eax        # Find out where the break is
        movl  $0, %ebx
        int   $LINUX_SYSCALL
        incl  %eax                  # %eax now has the last valid address, and
                                    # we want the memory location after that
        movl  %eax, current_break   # Store the current break
        movl  %eax, heap_begin      # Store the current break as our first
                                    # address. This will cause the allocate
                                    # function to get more memory from Linux
                                    # the first time it is run
        movl  %ebp, %esp            # Exit the function
        popl  %ebp
        ret

# allocate_init ends

# allocate starts

        # PURPOSE:  This function is used to grab a section of memory. It
        #           checks to see if there are any free blocks, and, if not,
        #           it asks Linux for a new one.
        #
        # PARAMS:   This function has one parameter - the size of the memory
        #           block we want to allocate
        #
        # RETURN:   This function returns the address of the allocated memory
        #           in %eax. If there is no memory available, it will return 0
        #           in %eax
        #
        #           %ecx - size of the requested memory (first/only parameter)
        #           %eax - current memory region being examined
        #           %ebx - current break position
        #           %edx - size of current memory region
        #
        # We scan through each memory region starting with heap_begin. We look
        # at the size of each one, and if it has been allocated. If it's big
        # enough for the requested size, and its available, it grabs that one.
        # If it does not find a region large enough, it asks Linux for more
        # memory. In that case, it moves current_break up

        .globl malloc
        .type malloc,@function

        # Stack position of the memory size to allocate

        .equ ST_MEM_SIZE, 8

malloc:

        pushl %ebp                     # Standard function stuff
        movl  %esp, %ebp

        movl  $0, %edi
        movl  heap_begin, %eax         # If heap_begin is 0, call allocate_init
        cmpl  %eax, %edi
        je    heap_empty
        jne   heap_nonempty

heap_empty:

        call allocate_init

heap_nonempty:

        movl  ST_MEM_SIZE(%ebp), %ecx  # %ecx will hold the size we are looking
                                       # for (which is the first and only
                                       # parameter)

        movl  heap_begin, %eax         # %eax will hold the current
                                       # search location

        movl  current_break, %ebx      # %ebx will hold the current break

alloc_loop_begin:                      # Here we iterate through each memory
                                       # region

        cmpl  %ebx, %eax               # Need more memory if these are equal
        je    move_to_break

        # Grab the size of this memory

        movl  HDR_SIZE_OFFSET(%eax), %edx

        # If the space is unavailable, go to the next one

        cmpl  $UNAVAILABLE, HDR_AVAIL_OFFSET(%eax)
        je    next_location

        cmpl  %edx, %ecx               # If the space is available, compare the
        jle   allocate_here            # size to the needed size. If its big
                                       # enough, go to allocate_here

next_location:

        addl  $HEADER_SIZE, %eax       # The total size of the memory region
        addl  %edx, %eax               # is the sum of the size that was
                                       # requested when this block was created
                                       # (currently stored in %edx), plus
                                       # another 8 bytes for the header (4 for
                                       # the Available/Unavailable flag, and 4
                                       # for the Size of the region). So,
                                       # adding %edx and $8 to %eax will get
                                       # the address of the next memory region

        jmp   alloc_loop_begin         # Go look at the next location

allocate_here:                         # If we've made it here, that means that
                                       # the region header of the region to
                                       # allocate is in %eax

        movl  $UNAVAILABLE, HDR_AVAIL_OFFSET(%eax)  # Mark space as unavailable

        addl  $HEADER_SIZE, %eax       # Move %eax past the header to the
                                       # usable memory (since that's what we
                                       # return)

        movl  %ebp, %esp               # Return from the function
        popl  %ebp
        ret

# If we've made it here, that means that we have exhausted all addressable
# memory, and we need to ask for more. %ebx holds the current endpoint of the
# data, and %ecx holds its size

move_to_break:                    # We need to increase %ebx to where we _want_
                                  # memory to end, so we add space for the
        addl  $HEADER_SIZE, %ebx  # headers structure and add space to the
                                  # break for the data requested
        addl  %ecx, %ebx


        # Now its time to ask Linux for more memory

        pushl %eax                # Save needed registers
        pushl %ecx
        pushl %ebx

        movl  $SYS_BRK, %eax      # Reset the break (%ebx has the requested
                                  # break point)
        int   $LINUX_SYSCALL

# Under normal conditions, this should return the new break in %eax, which will
# be either 0 if it fails, or it will be equal to or larger than we asked for.
# We don't care in this program where it actually sets the break, so as long as
# %eax isn't 0, we don't care what it is

        cmpl  $0, %eax            # Check for error conditions
        je    error

        popl  %ebx                # Restore saved registers
        popl  %ecx
        popl  %eax

        # Set this memory as unavailable, since we're about to give it away

        movl  $UNAVAILABLE, HDR_AVAIL_OFFSET(%eax)

        # Set the size of the memory

        movl  %ecx, HDR_SIZE_OFFSET(%eax)

        # Move %eax to the actual start of usable memory.
        # %eax now holds the return value

        addl  $HEADER_SIZE, %eax

        movl  %ebx, current_break  # Save the new break

        movl  %ebp, %esp           # Return the function
        popl  %ebp
        ret

error:

        movl  $0, %eax             # On error, we return zero
        movl  %ebp, %esp
        popl  %ebp
        ret

# allocate ends

# deallocate starts

        # PURPOSE:  The purpose of this function is to give back a region of
        #           memory to the pool after we're done using it.
        #
        # PARAMS:   The only parameter is the address of the memory we want to
        #           return to the memory pool.
        #
        # RETURN:   There is no return value
        #
        # If you remember, we actually hand the program the start of the memory
        # that they can use, which is 8 storage locations after the actual
        # start of the memory region. All we have to do is go back 8 locations
        # and mark that memory as available, so that the allocate function
        # knows it can use it.

        .globl free
        .type free,@function

        # Stack position of the memory region to free

        .equ ST_MEMORY_SEG, 4

free:

        # Since the function is so simple, we don't need any of the fancy
        # function stuff

        # Get the address of the memory to free (normally this is 8(%ebp), but
        # since we didn't push %ebp or move %esp to %ebp, we can just do
        # 4(%esp))

        movl  ST_MEMORY_SEG(%esp), %eax

        # Get the pointer to the real beginning of the memory

        subl  $HEADER_SIZE, %eax

        # Mark it as available

        movl  $AVAILABLE, HDR_AVAIL_OFFSET(%eax)

        ret

# deallocate ends
```

This is cross-compiled in a 64-bit system as follows:

```
as --32 alloc-lib.asm -o alloc-lib.o
ld --shared "-melf_i386" alloc-lib.o -o alloc-lib.so
```

However, it just results in `segfault` when I test it on a 32-bit system using something like:

```
LD_PRELOAD=./alloc-lib.so ls
```

I decided to write a simple C program to allocate an integer 1 to test it, but couldn't even make the `printf` function call. It `segfault`s too!

Finally, I modified the C program to dump the bytes using `putchar` from the new memory location to a file and validated the value using `hexdump`. `putchar` `API` worked without `segfault`s.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int *ptra;
    char *cptra;
    ptra = malloc(4);
    *ptra = 1;
    cptra = ptra;
    putchar(*cptra);
    putchar(*(cptra + 1));
    putchar(*(cptra + 2));
    putchar(*(cptra + 3));
    free(ptra);
}
```

1. Does anyone know why does it `segfault` with `ls` and `printf`
   function call? Assuming this could be because I haven't implemented `realloc` etc, wouldn't the program just use the standard `realloc`?
2. Is this above test case a reasonable one? I am just allocating an integer using my new `malloc`, `free`ing it, dumping it to a file and validating it with `hexdump`?

This is an exercise from the [Programming from Ground Up](https://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/pgubook/) book.

Comment: You need to override not just `malloc` and `free`, but all the other memory allocation functions as well.  Note further that stdio uses these functions internally for buffer management, so unless you ignore stdio completely, there is no way around this. Tell me what operating system and libc you are programming for and I can try and find out which functions these are.

Comment: Okay Thank You, @fuz. I am using `Arch Linux` running a `32-bit chroot` environment with `ldd (GNU libc) 2.12`. As long as you say I need those additional functions, then I think that should be a *sufficient* answer for now (you needn't debug and tell me the function names, will save that for later). Is the alternative test case fine in that case? It really helps to know that the program isn't having a problem.

Comment: I don't see an alternative test case anywhere.  One simple thing you can do is replacing your calls to `putchar` with calls to `write` (refer to the manual for how to call `write`). As `write` is a system call, it doesn't involve any memory allocation at all and you should not run into problems.

Comment: `putchar` works, `printf` doesn't. I just dumped each of the integer's `bytes` literally to a file and validated that the value is indeed the integer 1 (in `long`) format using `hexdump`.

Comment: I guess `putchar` is simple enough not to require dynamic memory allocation whereas `printf` is.

Comment: Okay, but I am doing `malloc` in my program to store an integer 1 and then `free`ing it. So, basically I am doing the memory management in my simple program itself.

Comment: Yeah, but `printf` calls `malloc` and other memory management functions like `realloc` which you don't wrap, causing the observed problems.

Comment: So @fuz if I didn't wrap `realloc`, wouldn't it fallback to the `realloc` that is part of the library? I thought fallback was obvious. Do you mean the logic here and there might be conflicting to cause this problem?

Comment: Yes it would.  `realloc` accesses internal datastructures of `malloc`.  If you pass a pointer to memory that wasn't allocated by the library's `malloc`, behaviour is undefined and your program probably crashes.  Why do you expect the libc's `realloc` to be able to deal with blocks you allocated from your own code?